# Why destructor being called twice after calling std::vector::pop_back()?

Tags: c++

I am confused with the output of this code.

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "Destructor called: " << this << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a, aa;
    std::vector<A> arr;

    arr.push_back(a);
    arr.push_back(aa);

    arr.pop_back();
    cout << "finish" << endl;    
}
```

This gives output as

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called: 0x561568fa92c0
Destructor called: 0x561568fa92e4
finish
Destructor called: 0x561568fa92e0
Destructor called: 0x7ffe51288a4c
Destructor called: 0x7ffe51288a48
```

So here's the thing why is the destructor invoked twice after calling pop_back(). And also which objects are being destroyed before **finish** is printed. Also does push_back() creates a copy of the objects passed to it?

Comment: I would expect a call to `pop_back` to produce a destructor call, since you're destroying an `A` object. The other destructor is probably due to a reallocation caused by the second `push_back`. What happens if you write `b.arr.reserve(2);` before adding elements?

Comment: "does push_back() creates a copy of the objects passed to it?" Yes. See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) for `push_back`. Specifically, for the overload that takes a `const` lvalue reference, "1) The new element is initialized as a copy of `value`."

Comment: You _should_ have have the constructor print the value of `this` also.

Comment: The compiler-generated copy constructor doesn't generate any output. Add a copy constructor to your instrumentation.

Comment: There are TONS of duplicates of this question on StackOverflow. A simple Google search for [`stackoverflow.com c++ vector destructor called twice`](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+vector+destructor+called+twice) reveals many of them. Please take the time to search existing questions before asking new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to better understand what is going on you need to define at least copy constructor, which is invoked by `push_back`:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "Constructor called: " << this << endl;
    }

    A(const A& other) {
        cout << "Copy Constructor called: " << this << " from: " << &other << endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "Destructor called: " << this << endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    vector<A> arr;
};

int main() {
    A a, aa; // creates two objects, so 2 constructors are invoked (#1, #2)
    B b;

    cout << "push a" << endl;
    b.arr.push_back(a); // new object is created via copy constructor (#3)
    cout << "push aa" << endl;
    b.arr.push_back(aa); // new object is created via copy constructor (#4)

    // also, during this time internal data structure of vector is resized, so #3 is copied again, this is #5
    // #3 is destructed during that time

    cout << "pop" << endl;
    b.arr.pop_back(); // popping #4 and call destructor, as it is not used
    cout << "finish" << endl;

    return 0;
    // destructor is called for #5, #2, #1
}
```

this is the output:

```
Constructor called: 000000000014FC94 (#1)
Constructor called: 000000000014FCB4 (#2)
push a
Copy Constructor called: 0000000000428FC0 (#3) from: 000000000014FC94 (#1)
push aa
Copy Constructor called: 0000000000427271 (#4) from: 000000000014FCB4 (#2)
Copy Constructor called: 0000000000427270 (#5) from: 0000000000428FC0 (#3)
Destructor called: 0000000000428FC0 (#3)
pop
Destructor called: 0000000000427271 (#4)
finish
Destructor called: 0000000000427270 (#5)
Destructor called: 000000000014FCB4 (#2)
Destructor called: 000000000014FC94 (#1)
```

Answer (score -1):

> why is the destructor invoked twice after calling pop_back().

It's not.

```
int main()
{
    A a, aa;
    std::vector<A> arr;

    arr.push_back(a);
    arr.push_back(aa);
    std::cout << "checkpoint\n";
    arr.pop_back();
    std::cout << "finish" << endl;    
}
```

[produces the output](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:27,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:27),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Ausing+std::cout%3B%0Ausing+std::endl%3B%0A%0Aclass+A+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++A()+%7B%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+%22Constructor+called%22+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++%7EA()+%7B%0A++++++++cout+%3C%3C+%22Destructor+called:+%22+%3C%3C+this+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++A+a,+aa%3B%0A++++std::vector%3CA%3E+arr%3B%0A%0A++++arr.push_back(a)%3B%0A++++arr.push_back(aa)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22checkpoint%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++arr.pop_back()%3B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+%22finish%22+%3C%3C+endl%3B++++%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+8.3%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
Constructor called
Constructor called
Destructor called: 0x1717ec0
checkpoint
Destructor called: 0x1717ee1
finish
Destructor called: 0x1717ee0
Destructor called: 0x7fff0884d86e
Destructor called: 0x7fff0884d86f
```

showing that only one destructor call is associated with `pop_back()`

Comment: not the downvoter: You might want to explain where that first destructor called line comes from, as it might not be obvious to other people.  Took me a minute to realize where it came from myself.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Part of the point I'm making is that OP hasn't done even a de minimus amount of investigation before asking his question.  Simply adding more markers in the output will quickly reveal at what point the extra move and destruction occur.

Comment: *the extra move and destruction occur.* `A` is not movable.